# Rails: store versions of model data and confirm changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My model (called **document**) is related to two different users. Both of them can edit the document, but the change needs to be accepted by the other.

For example: Bob and John share the same *document*. Bob add a new line to the document, so John receives a notification for accepting or rejecting the change.

How can i design the model class for dealing with this scenario? Is there any gem for this? Or at least, is there any gem that can help me for dealing with some part of it?

Thanks

Comment: Something like acts_as_versioned (though I don't know the details myself, just recall the name)?

Comment: But the act_as_versioned doesn't have the feature for the accepting/rejecting changes, does it?

Comment: You could put a field in your model to hold an acceptance of a version by the other party (if accepted is filled/true, prevent a rollback) and verify that the accepter isn't the person who made the change, whereas a rejection could trigger an automatic rollback to the previous version.

Comment: Are you actually storing the document in the database?

Comment: No, its an example... the document is just the class name. It has fields (that i want to track the revision): title, description, etc.